# Correct spelling/italicization of e.g., i.e.?

Tags: punctuation, latin, italics

Should e.g. and i.e. have periods, e.g. "e.g.", or no periods, eg "eg"? Should they be italicized, *e.g.* "*i.e.*" or not, eg "i.e"?

Comment: At the very least, i.e. should have periods so as not to confuse it with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In formal contexts, I would go with "e.g." and "i.e.", with two periods and without a whitespace. The spellings without periods are quite popular, but informal. For example, Merriam-Webster does not have an entry for either "eg" or "ie". Wiktionary [marks "eg." and "eg" as informal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e.g.), and offers the following [usage notes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e.g.#Usage_notes):

> - Opinion is mixed about whether this term should be italicized as although it is Latin, it has become part of standard English, and whether it should be written with a separating space "e. g." as it was originally two separate words.

It also offers the following [usage notes for "i.e."](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/i.e.#Usage_notes):

> - Opinion is mixed about whether the abbreviation should be italicized, or whether there should be a separating non-breaking space as in **i. e.**.
> - **ie** is often found in current usage, and is perhaps now considered acceptable.

Personally, I would argue that there's no need whatsoever to italicize "e.g." or "i.e.". Both expressions are extremely common in English, and have been for a long time. They are full-fledged citizens of the English language, and as such, they do not have to be italicized as if they were foreign words.

Answer (score 3):

eg & ie should be: e.g., and i.e., Don't forget the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Most style guides I have seen also say no *italics* for e.g. or i.e. — they are common Latin abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

*I.e.* and *e.g.* are written without periods in AMA style (10th edition).